# Accessing dynamic style variables (location) in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

I'll try making my question as clear as possible.

Generally speaking, how can I get a component location attribute: left, top etc') if it changes constantly?

Specifically:

I've created a component in react-native that is animating left and top properties of his son styles (this is an the code for the component animating the left position of the object):

```
class MovementAnimation extends Component {
  state = {
    moveAnim: new Animated.Value(100),  // Initial value for left: 100
  }

    componentDidMount() {                   //Call the animation
        this.runMovementAnimation()
    }

    runMovementAnimation(){
        var firstPosRand = parseInt(randomize('0', 3)) % 300;
        var secondPosRand = parseInt(randomize('0', 3)) % 300;
        var firstTimeRand = (parseInt(randomize('0',5)) % 3000) + 3000; //Stupid temporary solution to set a number between 500-3500
        var secondTimeRand = (parseInt(randomize('0',5))% 3000) + 3000;   

        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(this.state.moveAnim, {
              toValue: firstPosRand,                   // Animation
              duration: firstTimeRand
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.moveAnim, {
              toValue: secondPosRand,
              duration: secondTimeRand
            })
            ]).start(() => this.runMovementAnimation())         // repeat the animation
    }

  render() {
    let { moveAnim } = this.state;

    return (
      <Animated.View  ref='myElement'               // Special animatable View
        style={{
          ...this.props.style,
          left: moveAnim,         // Bind opacity to animated value
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in my mainPage I'm controlling a circle component I've made with this animation component, and it works great. BUT, I want to use this specific circle 'left' attribute to control a different one, how can I access it from a different class?

Thanks in advance!
Amit